# Session Invalidation of Community User in Custom application

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforce1-app, remote-action

I have a community app which calls remoteaction apis from app. I have a test scenario where the same app (after community user login) is opened from two different tabs of the browser. Both tabs might have same page or different page visible.

Now, form one of the tab community user clicks on logout button and from the other tab, user clicks on some link which calls to a remote action api. Whats happening is, the call is going to the remoteaction api and a valid response is returned. [its just a valid error response not the expected response with data (what i mean here is its not the same response which we get in positive scenario but the api is getting called)].

But what I was expecting that session invalidation error on the app but its not happening. Anyone faced this kind of scenario where its happening and if yes then what would be the resolution for the same (might be some permission settings or like that).